# Time shift in time format as input, the shifted real time as output

Tags: java, android, time, timer, formatting

Please, how could I:

- to input (not using timepicker) a time shift, for example as 02:21:22
- then to display a clock with the time shift added to it.

So if the time is currently 13:20:31 the displayed time would be 15:41:53 ...

Comment: You want to add 02:21:22 with 13:20:31?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want some thing like the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for the time addition. Example:

```
Calendar future = Calendar.getInstance();
future.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, enteredHour);
future.add(Calendar.MINUTE, enteredMinute);
future.add(Calendar.SECOND, enteredSecond);
//And so on...
//Now the calendar instance 'future' holds the current time plus the added values.
```

As for entering the time, one possibility is to enter it as a text, and then use a [`DateFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) from it. Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date enteredDate = sdf.parse(string); //String can be the input from an edit-text for example.
//You can now get the hours/minutes/seconds from the date with any of the Dates get-methods.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This function returns the formatted string of current time, shifted by time interval, </br>
 * set in "shift" parameter, formatted in the same way.
 * @param shift
 * @return
 * @throws ParseException
 */
static String addToCurrent(String shift) throws ParseException {
    long now=System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date shiftDate=df.parse(shift);
    long shiftedLong= shiftDate.getTime()+now;
    return df.format(shiftedLong);
}
```